# How to display a tooltip when the mouse pointer is over a YUI context menu item

Tags: javascript, yui, tooltip

In our workspace, there is a context menu created using the YUI library. We want to trigger a tooltip when the user hovers over each item. I googled around but could not find useful information. How can we accomplish this?

Here is how the context menu is created:

```
        // Add ContextMenu instance to the DataTable parent container
        var contextMenu = new YAHOO.widget.ContextMenu("contextMenu", {trigger: viewScriptsDataTable.getTbodyEl(), itemData: contextMenuItems, lazyload: true});
        contextMenu.render("viewScriptsGrid");

        // Subscribe to events in format event, function, object to pass to function
        contextMenu.beforeShowEvent.subscribe(CodesGrid.updateSelectionIfNecessary, viewScriptsDataTable);
        contextMenu.subscribe("click", CodesGrid.onContextMenuClick, viewScriptsDataTable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the text in a span and set the title attribute

```
  var contextMenuItems = [
    {text:"<span title'Cut'>Cut <em class='helptext'>Ctrl + X</em></span>"},
    {text:"<span title'Copy'>Copy <em class='helptext'>Ctrl + C</em></span>"},
    {text:"<span title'Paste'>Paste <em class='helptext'>Ctrl + V</em></span>"}
  ];
```

Or you could build the menu from existing html so you can set the title attribute:

```
<div id="editmenu" class="yuimenu">
    <div class="bd">
        <ul class="first-of-type">
            <li class="yuimenuitem">
                <a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href="#" title="Cut">
                    Cut <em class="helptext">Ctrl + X</em>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="yuimenuitem">
                <a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href="#" title="Copy">
                    Copy <em class="helptext">Ctrl + C</em>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="yuimenuitem">
                <a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href="#" title="Paste">
                    Paste <em class="helptext">Ctrl + V</em>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    </div>
</div>
```